# Python function partial string match

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
a      b      c
foo    bar    baz
bar    foo    baz
foobar barfoo baz
```

I've defined the following function in python:

```
def somefunction (row):
    if row['a'] == 'foo' and row['b'] == 'bar':
        return 'yes'
    return 'no'
```

It works perfectly fine. But I need to make a small tweak to the `if` function to take into account `partial string` matches.

I've tried several combinations, but I can't seem to get it to work. I get the following error:

`("'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')`

The function Iv'e tried is:

```
def somenewfunction (row):
    if row['a'].str.contains('foo')==True and row['b'] == 'bar':
        return 'yes'
    return 'no'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for boolean mask and then [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df['a'].str.contains('foo') & (df['b'] == 'bar')
print (m)
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

df['new'] = np.where(m, 'yes', 'no')
print (df)
        a       b    c  new
0     foo     bar  baz  yes
1     bar     foo  baz   no
2  foobar  barfoo  baz   no
```

Or if need alo check column `b` for substrings:

```
m = df['a'].str.contains('foo') & df['b'].str.contains('bar')
df['new'] = np.where(m, 'yes', 'no')
print (df)
        a       b    c  new
0     foo     bar  baz  yes
1     bar     foo  baz   no
2  foobar  barfoo  baz  yes
```

If need custom function, what should be slowier in bigger `DataFrame`:

```
def somefunction (row):
    if 'foo' in row['a'] and row['b'] == 'bar':
        return 'yes'
    return 'no'

print (df.apply(somefunction, axis=1))
0    yes
1     no
2     no
dtype: object
```

---

```
def somefunction (row):
    if 'foo' in row['a']  and  'bar' in row['b']:
        return 'yes'
    return 'no'

print (df.apply(somefunction, axis=1))
0    yes
1     no
2    yes
dtype: object
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

def somefunction (row):
    if 'foo' in row['a'] and row['b'] == 'bar':
        return 'yes'
    return 'no'

In [269]: %timeit df['new'] = df.apply(somefunction, axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 60.7 ms per loop

In [270]: %timeit df['new1'] = np.where(df['a'].str.contains('foo') & (df['b'] == 'bar'), 'yes', 'no')
100 loops, best of 3: 3.25 ms per loop
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

def somefunction (row):
    if 'foo' in row['a'] and row['b'] == 'bar':
        return 'yes'
    return 'no'

In [272]: %timeit df['new'] = df.apply(somefunction, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 614 ms per loop

In [273]: %timeit df['new1'] = np.where(df['a'].str.contains('foo') & (df['b'] == 'bar'), 'yes', 'no')
10 loops, best of 3: 23.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Ah yep. It's the `in row['a'] that I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is probably from the fact that you write

```
if row['a'].str.contains('foo')==True
```

Remove '.str':

```
if row['a'].contains('foo')==True
```